# Compute the e^{matrix}

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone help me out with the following question:

Compute $e^{A}$ for the following matrix:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 & -1 \\
      0 & 4 & -2 \\
      0 & 2 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
I've written $A=\begin{bmatrix}
                  2 & 0 & 0 \\
                   0 & 2 & 0\\
                   0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
               0 & 1 & -1 \\
                0 & 2 & -2 \\
                 0 & 2 & -2\\
\end{bmatrix}=D+N$ with D diagonal and N nilpotent.
Now I thought: $e^{A}=e^{D+N}=e^2 I e^N=e^2[I+N]=\begin{bmatrix}
e^2& e^2 & -e^2 \\
0 & 3e^2 & -2e^2 \\
0 & 2e^2 & -e^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$.
But this isn't the same as the answer if I compute it with for example maple. Does anyone see my mistake?

Comment: Looks ok to me. Show us your maple code?

Comment: It's possible that you made a mistake with your inputs into maple, instead.

Comment: @RoosJansen: I also verified your solution and it is correct. Likely a Maple input type issue or something like that.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct; your Maple code is not.

The analogous calculations in Mathematica are probably

- `Exp[ {
  {2, 1, -1},
  {0, 4, -2},
  {0, 2, 0}
  } ]` which exponentiates each element of the matrix individually

and

- `MatrixExp[ {
  {2, 1, -1},
  {0, 4, -2},
  {0, 2, 0}
  } ]` which actually computes the genuine quantity $e^A$ which you are interested in

which give respectively $$
e^A \neq \pmatrix{
 e^2 & e & \frac{1}{e} \\
 1 & e^4 & \frac{1}{e^2} \\
 1 & e^2 & 1
}, \qquad e^A =  \pmatrix{ e^2 & e^2 & -e^2 \\
 0 & 3 e^2 & -2 e^2 \\
 0 & 2 e^2 & -e^2 }$$

Comment: `Exp` simply threads over lists, and so it is not the proper function to use here (unless the matrix is a diagonal matrix). I think that including it is confusing.

Comment: @robjohn I included it entirely because I'm almost certain that was the mistake made by the OP (since it's entirely understandable). I added a couple more words in response to your comment, though no detail.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to compute the exponential of a matrix is using the Jordan decomposition.

The Jordan decomposition of your matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2&1&-1\\0&4&-2\\0&2&0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1&0\\1&-2&0\\1&-2&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2&0&0\\0&2&1\\0&0&2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1&0\\1&-2&0\\1&-2&1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
$$
Now, since the matrices commute, we can compute
$$
\begin{align}
\exp\left(\begin{bmatrix}
2&0&0\\0&2&1\\0&0&2
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
&=
\exp\left(\begin{bmatrix}
2&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&2
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
\exp\left(\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\right)\\[6pt]
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
e^2&0&0\\0&e^2&0\\0&0&e^2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align}
$$
Finally,
$$
\begin{align}
\exp\left(\begin{bmatrix}
2&1&-1\\0&4&-2\\0&2&0
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1&0\\1&-2&0\\1&-2&1
\end{bmatrix}
\exp\left(\begin{bmatrix}
2&0&0\\0&2&1\\0&0&2
\end{bmatrix}\right)
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1&0\\1&-2&0\\1&-2&1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\\
\end{align}
$$

---

I don't see anything wrong with your computation with the nilpotent matrix. In fact, I get the same result when  completing the computations above.